# Запрет параллельных запросов, модифицирующих те же данные в БД

Tags: java, многопоточность, api, rest, транзакции

На сайте есть механизм ввода какого нибудь промокода и получение за это разных плюшек. Но промокод активировать можно только один раз. Потом он уже невалидный. Происходит следующее:

1. Прилетает запрос
2. Идём в базу и смотрим есть ли такой промокод и не использовался ли он ранее
3. ...
4. ...
5. Идут остальные различные проверки
6. ...
7. ...
8. Помечаем промокод как активированный.

*Пример сильно упрощён и приведен только для наглядности.*

Проблема в том, что если скриптом в нескольких потоках запульнуть один и тот же промокод, то запросы прилетят одновременно и все пройдут дальше второго пункта(проверки на использовался или нет).

Как правильно поступать в таких случаях? Правильно ли будет вообще отсекать все последующие запросы(по коду/по юзеру), пока первый не отработал? Или же синхронизировать потоки?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Решение с синхронизацией потоков имеет ограничение, а именно, оно работает только в рамках одного процесса. Если производительности одного процесса будет не хватать и вы запустите несколько экземпляров вашего сервиса для распределения нагрузки - это решение сразу сломается.

Нужно синхронизироваться через БД.

Варианта тут два: пессимистическая и оптимистическая блокировки.

### Пессимистическая блокировка

Нужно делать все шаги от 2 до 8 в одной транзакции и на шаге 2 блокировать запись промокода при вычитывании его из БД. У вас уже есть запрос типа такого:

```
SELECT * FROM promo_code
```

Нужно его заменить на:

```
SELECT * FROM promo_code FOR UPDATE
```

Если несколько параллельных транзакций будут пытаться выполнить этот сценарий, то только одна сможет успешно пройти этот шаг. Остальные будут ждать пока та, которой удалось захватить блокировку на промо код, не закончится. И когда она закончится, следующая транзакция сможет захватить блокировку, и важно, что она увидит состояние промо кода уже с изменениями сделанными первой транзакцией. Т.е. вторая транзакция проверит, что промо код уже использован, и вернет ошибку клиенту.

Где происходит проверка, что промокод использован, т.е. при выполнении запроса в БД или уже в приложении - несущественно. В любом случае, вторая транзакция увидит результат первой.

### Оптимистическая блокировка

Для оптимистической блокировки нужно добавить в таблицу промокода поле версии. И при изменении его в БД на шаге 8 проверять, что никто до нас его не изменил с момента, как мы его прочитали на шаге 2. Опять же все нужно делать в одной транзакции.

Т.е. шаг 8 вместо:

```
UPDATE promo_code
SET activated = true
WHERE id = <promo_id>
```

меняется на

```
UPDATE promo_code
SET activated = true,
    version = version + 1
WHERE id = <promo_id>
   AND version = <promo_version>
```

`<promo_version>` это значение из поля версия, прочитанного на шаге 2.
При выполнении операции `update`, мы получаем результат - сколько записей было реально изменено в БД (JDBC API это всегда возвращает и все нормальные ORM-ы тоже позволяют узнать был ли реально сделан update записи). Если запись не изменилась, то значит, что параллельно другая транзакция изменила уже этот промокод пока наша выполнялась. В этом случае можно или вернуть ошибку или попытаться повторить все с шага 2. Что именно делать зависит от того, есть ли шанс, что повтор исправит ситуацию, а это определяется тем, какие операции в принципе возможны с промокодами.

### Что выбрать?

Однозначно сказать нельзя. Нужно взвешивать плюсы и минусы для конкретного случая.

У оптимистической блокировки преимущества в том, что она быстрее работает и требует меньше ресурсов сервера БД, если вероятность конфликта мала. Если же вероятность конфликта велика, то пессимистическая может оказаться лучше.

У пессимистическую блокировки преимущество, что ее проще реализовать.

Минусом пессимистической блокировки, является то, что если в транзакции нужно блокировать больше одной записи, то без должного внимания, могут возникать [взаимные блокировки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0).

Comment: Спасибо за подробное объяснение