# Mysql, состояние гонки

Tags: mysql

В базе данных есть запись **со статусом false**. Я ее достаю, делаю некоторые изменения, после чего я ее обновляю, **меняя ее статус на true.**

Параллельно запущен код, который может эту запись удалить, если она **false**.

Как мне сделать блокировку тут?

Думал, использовать транзакцию, но есть проблема - она то заблокирует, но после того как снимет блокировку, удаление пролетит, если оно было инициировано, или я не прав?

Comment: Можно, конечно, блокировать... но, по-моему, куда как разумнее третий тип значения статуса, означающий "обрабатывается, не колыхать".

Comment: Кстати, вариант!

Comment: *но есть проблема - она то заблокирует, но после того как снимет блокировку, удаление пролетит, если оно было инициировано, или я не прав?* Если это "блокирование-обработка-изменение-разблокирование" - то неправ. После снятия блокировки изменение  сторонним процессом, если оно ждёт снятия блокировки, получит ошибку вследствие изменения записи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все правильно, удаление не сработает, и это правильно.

Эта ситуация нечем не отличается в плане логики от ситуации, когда вы изменили статус на `true` пять минут назад. В этом случае же delete не должен произойти.

Если вас беспокоит, то что пользователь в момент нажатия на кнопку `delete` видел, что запись находится в таком состоянии, в котором ее можно удалить, то тут ничего не поделаешь, это фундаментальная проблема в системе с конкурентным доступом. Информация, которую видит пользователь, всегда устаревшая. Самая точная информация о текущем состоянии находится в БД и ее будет видно в момент операции изменения и операция может не пройти.

Приложение должно в этом случае обработать правильно ошибку. Для некоторых операций можно сделать автоматически повтор или слить результат операции (например, если кто-то уже удалил, а тут пользователь тоже удаляет, результат то такой же, так что можно пользователя и не беспокоить). Если автоматически нельзя разрулить, то нужно показать пользователю что-то в духе "пока вы тут думали, кто-то уже поменял эту запись"

Альтернативой является получение объекта в эксклюзивный доступ. Так чтоб пока пользователь его меняет, никто другой не мог его менять, а только читать. Но это нужно реализовывать не транзакциями в БД, т.к. долго держать открытой транзакцию плохо (а тут будет долго, пользователь начал процесс изменений, а потом ушел в отпуск - и так и не закончил, все это время держать транзакцию в БД очень плохо).

Это делается флагом, который меняется в одной транзакции, когда пользователь делает операцию типа "получить экслюзивный доступ к объекту". А после того как пользователь собственно изменил, флаг снимается. Пока флаг установлен, модифицировать нельзя, это значить все операции модификации проверяют, что флаг не установлен.

Так же рекомендую почитать [Запрет параллельных запросов, модифицирующих те же данные в БД](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1283527/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%91%d0%94/1283535)