# Как не допустить двойную трату денег на балансе пользователя?

Tags: php, postgresql

В сайте существуют 2 таблицы

```
balances
id, owner_id, total
```

и

```
orders
id, product_id, price, created_timestamp
```

Пользователь заходит на сайт и нажимает под каким-то товаром кнопку купить, отправляется запрос на сервер, он обрабатывается скриптом php

в этом коде есть фрагмент

```
$query = pg_query("SELECT total from balances where owner_id = '$user_id'  LIMIT 1;");
    $total = pg_fetch_array($pg_query($query))[0];
    
    if ($total >= $product_price){
        $query = "UPDATE balances set total = total-'$product_price' where owner_id = '$user_id';
    INSERT into orders (product_id, price, created_timestamp) VALUES ('$product_id','$product_price','$timestamp');";
    }
```

мне кажется этот фрагмент кода может стать уязвимостью в сайте,в случае если пользователь быстро отправит условную 1000 запросов к серверу, то т.к. эти запросы обрабатываются параллельно, то несколько запросов могут получить баланс пользователя до его изменения и в итоге могут создаться два и более заказов, а баланс пользователя уйдёт в минус

мои знания в как в базах , так и в языках программирования достаточно скромны, поэтому мне не приходит в голову ни одного решения кроме как создания сервиса, с которым этот скрипт будет соединяться, чтобы передать запрос. А этот сервис уже проверяет балансы и добавляет заказы, используя только один поток
этот вариант мне не очень нравится, тк это очень сильно режет максимальную нагрузку на сайт

хотелось бы каким-то образом заблокировать строку балансов этого пользователя для чтения и изменения одним и тем же запросом с SELECT total и разблокировать только после вычитания цены товара

Возможно ли это как-то сделать или подойдёт какой-то другой способ?

Comment: одно слово: транзакция.... и ещё два: уровень изоляции

Comment: и еще одна команда `select for update`

Comment: Почитайте тут. Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запрет параллельных запросов, модифицирующих те же данные в БД](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1283527/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%91%d0%94)

Comment: *а баланс пользователя уйдёт в минус* Есть такая фигня как CHECK constraint. Или просто UNSIGNED типы данных. И вот хоть на пупе извернись, а никакого "в минус" они не допускают, даже теоретически.