# Какие могут возникнуть проблемы при использовании прямого запроса на увеличение поля в базе данных?

Tags: python, sql, база-данных, postgresql, запрос

Существуют ли причины не использовать запрос вида "Update X = X + Y" при работе с базой данных? Насколько этот вид запроса менее/более оптимизирован, нежели получение значения X и обновление другим запросом?

Comment: Если 2 клиента возьмут Х, локально сделают +1 и потом отправят в бд апдейт - то результат будет явно не тот, которого вы ждете. Так что приведенный выше запрос лучше делать именно вида х = х + 1

Comment: @SwaD ещё и строку надо заблокировать. Кстати merge оператор по строкам атомарный?

Comment: @eri вот с merge почти не работал. Этоже по сути замена конструкции insert or update. Правда про вставку записей в вопросе ничего нет.

Comment: В основном это про атомарность операций, конечно. А ещё про транзакции почитайте. Зачем они вообще нужны и т.д.

Comment: Insert or update в постгресе не хватает...

Comment: @eri [есть](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) в pg insert or update (aka upsert aka `insert ... on conflict ...`)

Comment: по поводу проверки и обеспечения актуальности данных при возможности параллельных изменений см. этот ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1283535/218971

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA но посмотри какой он няшный в mysql.  Апсерт из 9.4(или 9.6) я знаю... Но он такой громздкий.

Comment: Replace не  update