MySQL - изоляция транзакций для оплаты заказа и списания с баланса
Всем привет!
Вопрос про изоляцию транзакций друг от друга.
Есть 2 таблицы.
user
--
id int
balance int

order
--
id int
amount int
user_id int
status int

Нужно сделать оплату заказа со списанием денег с баланса пользователя, проверив, что у него хватает денег.
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT balance FROM user WHERE id = 1;
SELECT amount FROM order WHERE id = 10 AND user_id = 1;
# далее тут идет проверка в коде, что баланс пользователя больше или равен стоимости заказа 
# и если да, то обновляем записи - вычисляем сколько у пользователя останется на балансе 
# и выставляем статус оплачено на заказ.
UPDATE user SET balance = balance - 20 WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE order SET status = 2 WHERE id = 10;
COMMIT;

А что, если одновременно придет 2 запроса на оплату 2 заказов у одного пользователя. То есть дважды почти одновременно произойдут запросы, которые описаны выше. Получается, оба запроса прочитают баланс и увидят, что денег хватает. Затем они оба обновят все таблицы и баланс уйдет в минус. Проверил на реальной БД MySQL с дефолтным уровнем изоляции: при второй транзакции которая идет параллельно с первой она считывает баланс который уже изменила предыдущая транзакция и дальше на обновление она просто ждет когда сделает COMMIT первая транзакция и не смотря на то, что данные там уже другие, она успешно утрабатывает, перезаписывая обновленные первой транзакцией данные своими данными.
Вопрос следующий. Какой лучший способ, чтобы избежать подобных ситуаций? Например, чтобы вторая транзакция откатывалась, если первая уже изменила те же данные, которые хочет изменить вторая. Или чтобы вторая транзакция считывала только данные, которые получились после полной отработки первой транзакции? Может какие-то варианты еще лучше есть?

Думаю можно использовать SELECT FOR UPDATE

далее тут идет проверка в коде, что баланс пользователя больше или равен стоимости заказа За каким хреном? заняться больше нечем, что ли? Проверяй прямо в запросе. Если все условия выполнятся, апдейт проходит, изменено 2 записи, если нет - апдейт не проходит, изменено ноль записей. Всё. А поскольку это ОДИН запрос, то никаких интерференций и быть не может. PS. А что, на поле баланса не стоИт ограничение, что его значение не может быть отрицательным?

Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL? Читайте пункты 5, 2.3 и 3, и выкладывайте работоспособный и адекватный пример.

смотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1283527/218971

Пример реализации. Обработка выполнена в виде хранимой процедуры - чтобы не повторять сам запрос.
Процедура принимает номер ордера, который должен быть обработан. Если статус ордера равен 1, а баланс юзера не упадёт в минус, выполняется обработка, баланс корректируется, а статус ставится равным 2. В любом другом случае обработка не выполняется. Процедура возвращает 1, если обработка выполнена, и 0, если не выполнена.
Исходные данные
CREATE TABLE users (
  id int,
  balance int
  );
CREATE TABLE orders (
  id int,
  amount int,
  user_id int,
  status int
  );
INSERT INTO users VALUES (1,111), (2,222);
INSERT INTO orders VALUES (1,11,1,1), (2,22,1,1), (3,111,2,1), (4,222,2,1),(5,1,3,1),(6,1,1,0);
SELECT * FROM users;
SELECT * FROM orders;




id
balance




1
111


2
222






id
amount
user_id
status




1
11
1
1


2
22
1
1


3
111
2
1


4
222
2
1


5
1
3
1


6
1
1
0



Процедура обработки
CREATE PROCEDURE process_order (IN order_id INT, OUT status BOOLEAN)
BEGIN
  UPDATE users
  JOIN orders ON users.id = orders.user_id
  SET users.balance = users.balance - orders.amount,
      orders.status = 2
  WHERE orders.id = order_id
    AND users.balance >= orders.amount  -- проверка, что баланс достаточен
    AND orders.status = 1;              -- проверка, что статус единица
  SET status = (ROW_COUNT() = 2);
END

CALL process_order(1, @status);
SELECT * FROM users;
SELECT * FROM orders;
SELECT @status;

Баланс достаточен, обработка выполняется.



id
balance




1
100


2
222






id
amount
user_id
status




1
11
1
2


2
22
1
1


3
111
2
1


4
222
2
1


5
1
3
1


6
1
1
0






@status




1



CALL process_order(2, @status);
SELECT * FROM users;
SELECT * FROM orders;
SELECT @status;

Баланс достаточен, обработка выполняется.



id
balance




1
78


2
222






id
amount
user_id
status




1
11
1
2


2
22
1
2


3
111
2
1


4
222
2
1


5
1
3
1


6
1
1
0






@status




1



CALL process_order(3, @status);
SELECT * FROM users;
SELECT * FROM orders;
SELECT @status;

Баланс достаточен, обработка выполняется.



id
balance




1
78


2
111






id
amount
user_id
status




1
11
1
2


2
22
1
2


3
111
2
2


4
222
2
1


5
1
3
1


6
1
1
0






@status




1



CALL process_order(4, @status);
SELECT * FROM users;
SELECT * FROM orders;
SELECT @status;

Баланс НЕдостаточен, обработка НЕ выполняется.



id
balance




1
78


2
111






id
amount
user_id
status




1
11
1
2


2
22
1
2


3
111
2
2


4
222
2
1


5
1
3
1


6
1
1
0






@status




0



CALL process_order(5, @status);
SELECT * FROM users;
SELECT * FROM orders;
SELECT @status;

Несуществующий юзер, обработка НЕ выполняется.



id
balance




1
78


2
111






id
amount
user_id
status




1
11
1
2


2
22
1
2


3
111
2
2


4
222
2
1


5
1
3
1


6
1
1
0






@status




0



CALL process_order(6, @status);
SELECT * FROM users;
SELECT * FROM orders;
SELECT @status;

Исходный статус НЕ единица, обработка НЕ выполняется.



id
balance




1
78


2
111






id
amount
user_id
status




1
11
1
2


2
22
1
2


3
111
2
2


4
222
2
1


5
1
3
1


6
1
1
0






@status




0



fiddle
PS. Рекомендую расширить диагностику, и в переменной статуса возвращать условную причину отказа в выполнении операции.
Также можно добавить в запрос любые дополнительные проверки.

Спасибо за подробный ответ! Такой вопрос, представим, что 2 запроса как у вас пришли почти одновременно и у нас огромная БД. Насколько вероятен такой сценарий, что внутри себя MySQL по этим запросам проверит условие почти одновременно (он же сначала ищет что обновить по условию WHERE) и увидят, что баланс после операции достаточен и также почти одновременно обновят данные (выполнит часть SET запросов) и баланс уйдет в минус? Понятно, что если там int unsigned, то будет ошибка так как отрицательное значение запрещено. А если это signed, то возможен уход в минус, верно?

@kepesty Один запрос - это транзакция. Атомарность - помните? А потому описываемой интерференции быть просто не должно. Запрос сначала отбирает записи для изменения (причём не только те, которые изменятся, но и те, которые просто участвуют в изменении как поставщики данных), блокирует их (во всех таблицах), и только потом изменяет. А потому параллельный конкурирующий запрос ну никак не может прочитать те же данные и развалить целостность.
